# how can lookbehind positive work in pgsql regexp_replace?

Tags: regex, postgresql-9.6

The most simple test I've done is this one:

```
SELECT regexp_replace((09,09,41,41,42,42,49,49,49,49,200,200,400,400,500,500), '(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(,\\1)+(?=,|$)', '\\1') AS lignes
```

I would like to have what regex101 show me : 09,41,42,49,200,400,500.
But the entire string come.
Any help?

Comment: Do you mean you have `'09,09,41,41,42,42,49,49,49,49,200,200,400,400,500,500'` as input?

Comment: Yes, input AND output. Same, without any modification. And the regex is good in all testers.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to double the backslashes unless [`standard_conforming_strings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-compatible.html) is on:

> `standard_conforming_strings (boolean)`
>    This controls whether ordinary string literals ('...') treat backslashes literally, as specified in the SQL standard. Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.1, the default is on (prior releases defaulted to off). Applications can check this parameter to determine how string literals will be processed. The presence of this parameter can also be taken as an indication that the escape string syntax (E'...') is supported. Escape string syntax ([Section 4.1.2.2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE)) should be used if an application desires backslashes to be treated as escape characters.

Next, you need to use `g` global modifier to replace *all* matches, see the [*9.7. Pattern Matching* section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html):

> Flag `i` specifies case-insensitive matching, while flag `g` specifies replacement of each matching substring rather than only the first one.

Use

```
SELECT regexp_replace('09,09,41,41,42,42,49,49,49,49,200,200,400,400,500,500', '(?<=,|^)([^,]*)(,\1)+(?=,|$)', '\1', 'g') AS lignes
```

[image]

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/HAJYG62994).

If you want to make the pattern more efficient, use double negation:

```
'(?<![^,])([^,]*)(,\1)+(?![^,])'
```

Comment: Nice, nice nice! Thank you. I do need the double backslashes because of standard_conforming_strings turned off. Apart of that, this is perfect!

Just to understand: why do you prefer double negation?

Comment: "Note: If you have standard_conforming_strings turned off, any backslashes you write in literal string constants will need to be doubled. See Section 4.1.2.1 for more information." This is why I need double backslashes.

Comment: @Cy's Double negation is to improve performance since alternation always triggers backtracking.

Comment: @Cy's That is why I added that text there. Please consider accepting the answer since it worked for you.